# php/mysql account activation

Tags: php, mysql

Everything in my new website is working just fine, except that I can't get this piece of code to work:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE useremail = '$useremail'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$activation = $row['activation'];
if ($activation == '0') {
    die('Your account is not yet active. Please check your email!');
    exit();
}
```

In the database, the type is `enum('0', '1')` and the field name is `activation`.

Here is the error message I am getting:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result`

Could someone please give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: `echo` actual sql code, copy it to querybrowser and see the result.

Comment: Try: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE useremail = '$useremail'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Please tell me you're escaping `$useremail`

Comment: @Carlos can you post your DB Structure ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that your query is invalid:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE useremail = '$useremail'");
```

Are you doing any input sanitization for `$usermail`?

Are you sure your database contains that table and that the table contains that column.

Try doing a little debugging:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE useremail = '$useremail'";
echo $query;
```

and try running the content of `$query` directly in your database (from phpMyAdmin or something).

Comment: @Carlos what do you mean it connects fine? Have you tried what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

> Everything in my new website is working just fine

...until something goes wrong.

You have to learn **how to handle errors**.

run **all** your queries *at least* this way.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE useremail = '$useremail'"
$result = mysql_query() or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$query);
```

and you always be notified of any error and **it's reason**

or implement any other way of error notifications, employing **mysql_error()** function which is the only thing in the world that can tell you **where the actual problem is.**

Answer (score -1):

Change your first line to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE useremail = '$useremail'") or die(mysql_error());
```

And it will spit out the mysql error that is causing the Warning =)

You should not be presuming the call to `mysql_query` returns a valid result; It's good practice to always test the result first, e.g.

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * YADYADA");
if($r && mysql_num_rows($r)>0){
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
}else{
  //Uh oh, something's not right~~~ throw an exception maybe?
}
```

Comment: why exception for empty result ?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I didn't actually throw and exception, I was just hinting at one of the options on the table. An Exception would at least be a step more elegant than his `die()` call ;)

Comment: i see the problem now. Thank you.

Comment: well, your answer is just an offtopic. as it seems it will throw exceptions forever.